# Textfield within a textfield

Tags: java, swing

I have made a GUI calculator in net beans, this is what it looks like:

[image: GUI Calculator]

I was wondering if there is a way to insert a Text Field within a text field so I can display the operation that has been performed along with its result.

**i want to display the operation performed in the top left corner of    the same text field.**

I have tried to drag and drop a text field over the main Text Field, it just slides the previous `JTextField` to the right and inserts the second Text Field on the main panel. thanks in advance

Comment: Yes. But, I believe you will have to write code. Specifically, create a custom class that extends `JTextField` and draw your inner box before calling the `super` draw.

Comment: Wouldn't it be an option for you to use an [editorpane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/editorpane.html) and make it display two lines: result with the font size you are currently using and the second under it (or wherever you want) for the operation with a smaller font?

Comment: @A4L we haven't been taught `editorpane` in class and we were instructed to only use stuff that has been discussed in class for out projects. No way to do this through `JTextField` ?

Comment: Well the easiest you could do is take two components and tweak on the borders to make both appear as a single field as suggested by camickr.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> i want to display the operation performed in the top left corner of the same text field(hence textfield within a text field question). is that possible?

Create a panel with two components:

1. a JLabel on the left
2. a JTextField on the right.

You can get the `Border` of the text field and use it as the Border of the panel so that it looks like the two components are one component.

Comment: do you mean changing the text of the `JLabel` each time an operation is performed?

Comment: @UsamaKhurshid, if that is your requirement.

Comment: can you explain a bit more. for example how do i change the border of text field. also should i use another textfield for operation display or a jlabel and why?

Comment: `should i use another textfield for operation display or a jlabel` - your requirement is "_to DISPLAY the operation performed in the top left corner_" - so you tell me which component you should use and why?

Comment: Why? What is the purpose of a JLabel and a JTextField? Which one meets your simple requirement to "DISPLAY the operation"?

Comment: well i'm very new to java. would you do me a favor and not answer my question with another question?

Comment: took me a little time and experimenting to understand what you meant. thanks for your help :)

Comment: `would you do me a favor and not answer my question with another question?` In my original answer I areaday gave you my answer about which component to use. So, would you do the favour of answering my question. I asked you to choose a component and why. So why would you choose a JTextField over my suggestion? The point of me asking you if for you to think about my answer and if you don't agree, then tell my why you don't agree.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this with a textfield within a textfield. I would try to use a text control that is able to display both html text and multiple lines. Then you could add the two lines like

```
first line<br>secondline
```

wrapping the individual lines in  tags gives you the ability to apply different fonts.

Comment: i want to display the operation performed in the top left corner of the same text field(hence textfield within a text field question). is that possible? if yes, how?

Answer (score 0):

if you r using netbeans is pretty simple first you have to make you JTextFiled(Operation one opaque) use the properties to do it
so first you have to add a Jpanel which will contain the bouth Jtextfields then select the panel and set the layout property on NullLayout that will let you superpose your two JtextField then in the compenent viewer you have to make the operation textfield above the result textfield (to solve the z-order like in css) dont forget to make no border option for the operation textfield.
sorry for my english if you wanna help tell me i will see how to do

Comment: dont forget the setenabled(false). and to set it color

Comment: if you could take the time to demonstrate it, i'd be very thankful

Comment: it takes lot of time but i will give you tutorial from where i learned to do it you have to watch this
[useful tutorial about design](http://www.youtube.com/user/VertexDigitalArts/videos)
[the ones you need right now](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QA8V80WiZ6I) [2](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIPNM6PXm58)
[3](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wSkjMryBAjs)